# Comparison of trajectories from odometries

Tags: ros2, odometry, robot-localization, trajectory

Is there a way in ROS2 to compare trajectories from odometry data? I'm using robot_localization to calculate various odometry outputs by incorporating GPS and IMU data. I have a bag file where I recorded odometry topics, and I would like to compare the paths taken in the following configurations:

- /odom_local (odometry + IMU)
- /odom_global (odometry + IMU + GPS)
- /odom_ackermann (only my    odometry data)

I can visualize the trajectories in rviz2, but I also want to compare them in terms of distance error, etc.

If someone has already done this, I hope they can assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Plotjuggler](https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler). Its a nice tool for plotting and investigating data. You can directly import rosbags into it. Another good thing about plotjuggler is that you can plot X-Y plots which really helps in case of plotting odometry data. I have been using it for years now, It might take some time to setup and get started but it will be worth it.

Tip: you can plot goal (X-Y position) and over it your odometry(X-Y position) for each case and you'll see how deviated each one of them is from reference path (goal path).

Check out [this](https://vimeo.com/351160225) video by the author of plotjuggler and you'll understand more.

Hope this helps